# Webpack not exporting ES6 classes properly?

Tags: node.js, webpack

While trying to debug a larger problem, I've come up with a barebones module and Webpack configuration that seems to improperly export ES6 classes.

The module (`index.js`):

```
module.exports = class Foo {
    constructor() {
        console.log('foo!');
    }
}
```

And `webpack.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
    target: 'node',
    entry: './index.js',
    output: {
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    }
};
```

The output (`bundle.js`) is:

```
/******/ (function(modules) { // webpackBootstrap
/******/    // The module cache
/******/    var installedModules = {};
/******/
/******/    // The require function
/******/    function __webpack_require__(moduleId) {
/******/
/******/        // Check if module is in cache
/******/        if(installedModules[moduleId]) {
/******/            return installedModules[moduleId].exports;
/******/        }
/******/        // Create a new module (and put it into the cache)
/******/        var module = installedModules[moduleId] = {
/******/            i: moduleId,
/******/            l: false,
/******/            exports: {}
/******/        };
/******/
/******/        // Execute the module function
/******/        modules[moduleId].call(module.exports, module, module.exports, __webpack_require__);
/******/
/******/        // Flag the module as loaded
/******/        module.l = true;
/******/
/******/        // Return the exports of the module
/******/        return module.exports;
/******/    }
/******/
/******/
/******/    // expose the modules object (__webpack_modules__)
/******/    __webpack_require__.m = modules;
/******/
/******/    // expose the module cache
/******/    __webpack_require__.c = installedModules;
/******/
/******/    // define getter function for harmony exports
/******/    __webpack_require__.d = function(exports, name, getter) {
/******/        if(!__webpack_require__.o(exports, name)) {
/******/            Object.defineProperty(exports, name, {
/******/                configurable: false,
/******/                enumerable: true,
/******/                get: getter
/******/            });
/******/        }
/******/    };
/******/
/******/    // getDefaultExport function for compatibility with non-harmony modules
/******/    __webpack_require__.n = function(module) {
/******/        var getter = module && module.__esModule ?
/******/            function getDefault() { return module['default']; } :
/******/            function getModuleExports() { return module; };
/******/        __webpack_require__.d(getter, 'a', getter);
/******/        return getter;
/******/    };
/******/
/******/    // Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call
/******/    __webpack_require__.o = function(object, property) { return Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(object, property); };
/******/
/******/    // __webpack_public_path__
/******/    __webpack_require__.p = "";
/******/
/******/    // Load entry module and return exports
/******/    return __webpack_require__(__webpack_require__.s = 0);
/******/ })
/************************************************************************/
/******/ ([
/* 0 */
/***/ (function(module, exports, __webpack_require__) {

module.exports = __webpack_require__(1);


/***/ }),
/* 1 */
/***/ (function(module, exports, __webpack_require__) {

"use strict";


module.exports = class Foo {
    constructor() {
        console.log('foo!');
    }
}


/***/ })
/******/ ]);
```

When I try to use the `Foo` class from the bundle, I get this error:

```
TypeError: Foo is not a constructor
```

It works just fine using the source code, but not the bundled version. Is there anything I'm doing wrong with the Webpack config?

EDIT: I have discovered that in order to make it work properly, I have to wrap the class in an object. I tested a few other data types (exporting functions, numbers, etc.) and it seems that you must export an object for it to work properly.

Comment: Do you run your bundle in your browser or in the node engine?

Comment: If you're running this code exclusively with Node.js, its unnecessary to run the above through a Webpack transpilation.  ES6 Classes are already supported in Node, since [v4.8.7](http://node.green/#ES2015-functions-class)

Comment: @ChrisR To test, I was running it in node, but later I'm going to have 2 separate bundles for node and browser.

Comment: @peteb I realize that - later, I'll be using it to bundle in dependencies for the browser. I just had this issue with classes and made this test case as a reproducible example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just needed to add this to the Webpack config:

```
output: {
    libraryTarget: 'umd'
}
```

Comment: For anyone coming to this later, the recommended property to use is `output.library.type`.